# Sub Menu Text Color Cannot Be Changed In Wordpress Site

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navigation, submenu

I am having to work with wordpress to make modifications to a website. One of these modifications is to add new submenu items in my main navigation menu. I can add the items but I cannot seem change the text color to white(which is black now). I have tried all sorts of things and nothing seems to effect the 2nd level of the menu. I have added the menu item correctly . My page is located at [www.holidayatyourchoice.com](http://www.holidayatyourchoice.com/)

Comment: Please post your related CSS & HTML here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the CSS style for the menu... You don't have it for the Sub-Menu..

Just add this into your style.css

```
ul.sub-menu > li > a span span {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Enjoy

EDIT: to make the appear bold you can add `font-weight: 900;`

Comment: Thanks That Worked :) one more how to make it appear bold?

Comment: @Melvin hi Melvin, i've updated my answer, check if it suits your needs.